# query spark dataframe on max column value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I have a hive external partitioned table with following data structure:

```
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=foo/project_version=2.0/dt=20210105/file1.parquet
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=foo/project_version=2.0/dt=20210110/file2.parquet
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=foo/project_version=2.1/dt=20210201/file3.parquet
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=bar/project_version=2.0/dt=20210103/file4.parquet
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=bar/project_version=2.1/dt=20210210/file5.parquet
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=bar/project_version=2.1/dt=20210311/file6.parquet
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=big_project/project_version=1.1/dt=20210401/file7.parquet
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=big_project/project_version=1.1/dt=20210401/file8.parquet
hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=big_project/project_version=1.1/dt=20210401/file9.parquet
```

i want to return a dataframe containing data for foo project, for the max version.
i want to avoid reading records for any other project.
I'm unable to query this table directly due to limitations in our etl process, so have tried reading directly from parquet

```
val df_foo = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://my_server/stg/my_table/project=foo")
df_foo.printSchema

root
 |-- clientid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- some_field_i_care_about: string (nullable = true)
 |-- project_version: double (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: string (nullable = true)

df_foo.groupBy("project_version", "dt").count().show

+---------------+--------+------+
|project_version|      dt| count|
+---------------+--------+------+
|            2.0|20210105|187234|
|            2.0|20210110|188356|
|            2.1|20210201|188820|
+---------------+--------+------+

val max_version = df_foo.groupBy().max("project_version")
max_version.show

+--------------------+
|max(project_version)|
+--------------------+
|                 2.1|
+--------------------+

val df_foo_latest = df_foo.filter($"project_version" === max_version).count()

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset [max(project_version): double]
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:163)
  at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
```

project_version column is a double, and max_version value is also a double, why can't i compare these values in the filter?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_version` is of type `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` its not `Double`. You have to extract value from the DataFrame.

Check below code.

```
scala> val max_version = df.groupBy().agg(max("project_version").as("version")).as[Double].collect.head
max_version: Double = 2.1

scala> val df_foo = Seq((2.0,20210105,187234),(2.0,20210110,188356),(2.1,20210201,188820)).toDF("project_version","dt","count")
df_foo: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [project_version: double, dt: int ... 1 more field]

scala> val max_version = df_foo.groupBy().agg(max("project_version").as("version")).as[Double].collect.head
max_version: Double = 2.1

scala> val df_foo_latest = df_foo.filter($"project_version" === max_version).count()
df_foo_latest: Long = 1

scala> val df_foo_latest = df_foo.filter($"project_version" === max_version)
df_foo_latest: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [project_version: double, dt: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df_foo_latest.count
res1: Long = 1

scala> df_foo_latest.show(false)
+---------------+--------+------+
|project_version|dt      |count |
+---------------+--------+------+
|2.1            |20210201|188820|
+---------------+--------+------+
```

Instead of extracting value from DataFrame, try to use `inner` join. It's much safer.

```
scala> val max_version = df_foo.groupBy().max("project_version")
max_version: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [max(project_version): double]

scala> val max_version = df_foo.groupBy().agg(max("project_version").as("project_version"))

scala> val df_foo_latest = df_foo.join(max_version,Seq($"project_version"),"inner")


scala> df_foo_latest.show(false)
+---------------+--------+------+
|project_version|dt      |count |
+---------------+--------+------+
|2.1            |20210201|188820|
+---------------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks @srinivas, makes sense.  in your final code line, whats the purpose of `Seq($"project_version")` does that enable you to specify the join column thats common to both dataframes?  thanks

Comment: yes, when you have same columns in both dataframe you can specify `Seq($"project_version")`.